# replace '?' in a dataset with 0

Tags: r

I am working in R and have a dataset comprising of 700 rows and 10 columns, with some of the values having '?' as value. I want to replace the '?' values with 0.

I am not sure if the `is.na()` function would work here, as the values are not `NA`. If I convert my dataset into a matrix, and after searching for '?' , replace it with 0, would that help?

I tried this code:

```
datafile <- sapply(datafile, function(y){if (y=='?') 0 else y})
```

after this I saved the file as a text file, but the `?` didn't go away.

Comment: Have you looked at `?replace()`?

Comment: can you give me an example? That would be really helpful

Comment: Can you give me an example? that would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to convert to a matrix. As Ben Bolker said, your best option is to use `na.strings` when reading in the file.

If the data frame is not coming from a file, you can directly do:

```
df[df=="?"] <- 0
```

You have to remember though that anything containing character might be converted to a factor. If that's the case, you have to convert those factors to character. Ben gives you a brute force option, here's a more gentle approach:

```
# check which variables are factors
isfactor <- sapply(df, is.factor)
# convert them to character
# I use lapply bcs that returns a list, and I use the 
# list-like selection of "elements" (variables) to replace
# the variables
df[isfactor] <- lapply(df[isfactor], as.character)
```

So if you put everything together, you get:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,5,3,'?',4),
  b = c(3,'?','?',3,2)
)
isfactor <- sapply(df, is.factor)
df[isfactor] <- lapply(df[isfactor], as.character)

df[df=="?"] <- 0
df
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you have other `NA` values in your data set. If not, almost certainly the easiest way to do this is to use the `na.strings=` argument to `read.(table|csv|cv2|delim)`, i.e. read your data with something like `dd <- read.csv(...,na.strings=c("?","NA")`.  Then

```
dd[is.na(dd)] <- 0
```

If for some reason you don't have control of this part of the process (e.g. someone handed you a `.rda` file and you don't have the original CSV), then it's a bit more tedious -- you need

```
which.qmark <- which(x=="?")
x <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(x)))
x[which.qmark] <- 0
```

(This version also works if you have both `?` and other `NA` values in your data)